# WLST - force stop application

Tags: java, python, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I am currently working with weblogic and the thing is that I deploy several applications on my weblogic server. Sadly, when one of this application fail to deploy for X/Y reason, I just want to force stop this application and to pass to the other one.

I've already looked into the WLST doc and I don't find what I am searching for.
Here is the function I use :

`stopApplication(applicationName, gracefulProductionToAdmin="true", gracefulIgnoreSessions="true")`

It takes about 5 minutes to stop application this way. When I stop application through Administration Console (force stop actually) it takes about 5 seconds to stop application.
So is there any way to force stop application through WLST script?

Thanks

Comment: For me it did not work. I later realized that if you run the command without specifying the target host. I realized that running the command without specifying the target it tries to stop the application on the local host. After I have specified the target everything stopped instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again without the options. Just the stopApplication(appName).

This is what the admin console does, kills all existing sessions and drags it to prepared state. You are trying to stop it gradually and hence the delay.

You had mentioned, "`when one of this application fail to deploy for X/Y reason, I just want to force stop this application and to pass to the other one.`"
If an application fails to deploy, you should not have to stop it. If the App runs, its successful correct?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I had other works to do. By the way, it works well. Thanks !